# How to let a .myhtml file has colors as a html file in vim?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have a html file, it has good colors in vim.

But I want to define some custom file types, they have html content, but with different suffix names. e.g. index.html -> index.myhtml

But when I open "index.myhtml", it has no colors, only black and white.

How to let the vim treat the ".myhtml" as ".html"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. :set filetype=html
2. write in `.vimrc`

   `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.myhtml set filetype=html`